# PHP File upload fails after some time

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I am facing problem uploading files, getting errors after some time.
I am uploading files and inserting details into database about image like name date etc.

> What happens is that till no of uploaded file is 27 everything works
>   well but when I try to upload more than 27 file it start showing errors
>   like
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(../../images/2015/05/imvsa/kexk.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'D:\wamp\tmp\php3635.tmp' to '../../images/2015/05/imvsa/kexk.jpg'

my php.ini

```
max_execution_time     = 1440
max_input_time         = 1440
post_max_size          = 1024M
upload_max_filesize    = 1024M
max_file_uploads       = 10000
session.save_path      = "d:/wamp/tmp"
session.gc_maxlifetime = 7200
memory_limit           = 512M
```

If I truncate my database table then it starts working uptill row 27 and again it starts to fail.

my script

```
    if($_FILES['image']['size']<5242880&&getimagesize($_FILES['image'])!=false)
    {
        if(!is_dir('../../images/2015/05/'))
        {
          $mkdir = mkdir('../../images/2015/05/',  0777, true);
        }

        $info       = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $image      = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $ext        = $info['extension'];
        $temp_file  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $img_target ='../../images/2015/05/'.$image.'.'.$ext;
        $upload     = move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $img_target);
   }
// and now I do Insert in database
```

Please see and suggest any possible way to make it work, I an going to be uploading hundreds of image in a day with max size of 5MB.
Thanks

Comment: check the permission of your temp folder

Comment: upload_max_filesize = 1024M == Max file upload size 1MB rise it up to 5120M in order to upload up to 5M

Comment: @Zgr3doo: 1024M = 1GB... That will be enough no?

Comment: Have you tried dumping out the [file upload errors](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)?

For example: If you are uploading into /tmp and you are uploading that much files, perhaps it just runs out of disk space?

Comment: @Blizz Tall boY said that he wants to upload files up to 5M but php have setting set just to 1M
Tall boY check if you have this folder created ../../images/2015/05/imvsa/ with the correct permisions

Comment: Once more: 1024M is ONE GIGABYTE. You are thinking 1024K

Comment: I just increased php.ini value to test, Ill reset it to 5M when I get it resolved.

Comment: @Blizz  `if($_FILES['image']['error']) { 
   echo $_FILES['image']['error'];
 } else { 
   echo 'no errors';
 }`
shows no errors

Comment: It propbbly means that it's your webserver preventing the uploads. Don't know if you are running apache or nginx, but both have a max body size that you can configure. These settings come first, so you have to check them as well.

Comment: @Blizz I am working on localhost currently.

Comment: You still need a webserver that accepts your php requests... WAMP also contains aan apache server (the A in the name) with a configuration :)

Comment: @Blizz how I can check for max body size in WAMP

Comment: It's the [LimitRequestBody setting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) in `http.conf`

Comment: @Blizz I can not find anything about LimitRequestBody in http.conf

Comment: @TallboY did you import all 27 manually or in some cycle?

Comment: @LukasJahoda I upload images one by one in bulk and simultaneously insert data about images in database I do not import rows in database

Comment: @Blizz you right I must be blind :) - Tallboy are you uploading them in one go all those files ?

Comment: @Blizz no ten at a time

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(!is_dir('../../images/2015/05/imvsa/')){
  $mkdir = mkdir('../../images/2015/05/imvsa/',  0777, true);
}
```

Comment: this wont work as directory `imvsa` will be different for every image

Comment: @TallboY ok, but you must still create directory before use move_uploaded_file(); It is reason why you have this errors, because directory doesn't exists.

Comment: why is this error coming after I have successfully uploaded 27 files and getting error for 28th file.

Comment: If I truncate MySQL table this error goes away and file starts to upload uptill again 27th file

Comment: @TallboY what value do you have in $temp_file and what is realpath of ../../images/2015/05/
`var_dump(realpath('../../images/2015/05/'));`